# Fetching data from the server using useEffect, redux toolkit, axiso

Tags: reactjs, axios, frontend, redux-toolkit

When fetching from the server via redux toolkit, the data on the page is not updated. To do this, I created a separate refetch file where I save the added data through the toolkit. But it seems to me that it could be simpler.
Here is a selection of data with a dependency from refetch.

Favorite.tsx

```
interface IFavorite {
    openFavorite: boolean,
    setOpenFavorite: (value: boolean) => void;
}

const Favorite: React.FC<IFavorite> = ({openFavorite, setOpenFavorite}) => {

    const { favoriteList } = useAppSelector(refetch);

    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const favoriteItems = useAppSelector(favoriteItem);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(favoriteFetch());
    },[favoriteList]);

    return (
        <div className={`${styles.favorite} ${openFavorite ? styles.active : ''}`}>
                                    <div className={styles.favoriteHead}>
                                        <div className={styles.favoriteHeadTitle}>Избранное</div>
                                        <div onClick={() => setOpenFavorite(false)} className={styles.favoriteHeadClose}>X</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className={styles.favoriteTd}>
                                    {favoriteItems.length <= 0 
                                        ? <div className={styles.favoriteTdEmpty}>
                                            Нет избранных товаров
                                        </div>
                                        : favoriteItems.map(item => <FavoriteProduct key={item.id} id={item.id} img={item.img} title={item.title} price={item.price}/>)}
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
    )
};

export default Favorite;
```

Here is the logic of adding favorites

Products.tsx

```
interface IProduct {
    id: string,
    img: string,
    title: string,
    price: number,
}

const Products: React.FC<IProduct> = ({id, img, title, price}) => {

    const favorite = useAppSelector(favoriteList(id));
    const cart = useAppSelector(cartList(id));

    const props = {id, img, title, price};

    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const handleFavorite = () => {
        dispatch(addFavoriteRefetch({id, img, title, price}));
        
        if(favorite){
            dispatch(deleteFavoriteFetch(id))
        } else {
            dispatch(addFavoriteFetch(({id, img, title, price})))
        }     
    }

    const handleCart = () => {
        dispatch(addCartRefetch({id, img, title, price}))

        if(cart) {
            dispatch(updateCartFetch(cart));    
        } else {
            dispatch(addCartFetch({...props, count: 1}));
        }
        
    }
    
    return (
        <div className={styles.contentProducts}>
            <img onClick={handleFavorite} className={styles.contentProductsFavorite} src={favorite ? '/images/heartclick.png' : "/images/heart.png"} alt="" />
            <img className={styles.contentProductsImg} src={img} alt="" />
            <div className={styles.contentProductsOptions}>
                <div>
                    <p>{title}</p>
                    <div>Цена: {price} р.</div>
                </div>
                <button onClick={handleCart}>Добавить</button>  
            </div>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Products
```

Here are my server requests

favoriteSlice.tsx

```
export const favoriteFetch = createAsyncThunk<IFavorite[]>(
    'favorite/favoriteFetch',
    async () => {
        const {data} = await axios.get<IFavorite[]>('http://localhost:3001/favorite');
        return data;
    }
) 

export const addFavoriteFetch = createAsyncThunk(
    'addFavorite/addFavoriteFetch',
    async (params: IFavorite) => {
        await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/favorite', params);
    }
)

export const deleteFavoriteFetch = createAsyncThunk(
    'deleteFavorite/deleteFavoriteFetch',
    async (id: string) => {
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/favorite/${id}`)
    }
)

const enum Status {
    LOADING = 'Loading',
    SUCCES = 'completed',
    ERROR = 'error',
}

interface IFavorite {
    id: string,
    img: string,
    title: string,
    price: number,
}

interface IFavorites {
    list: IFavorite[],
    status: Status,
}

const initialState: IFavorites = {
    list: [],
    status: Status.LOADING,
}

export const favoriteSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'favorite',
    initialState,
    reducers: {

    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(favoriteFetch.pending, (state) => {
            state.status = Status.LOADING;
        });
        builder.addCase(favoriteFetch.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.list = action.payload;
            state.status = Status.SUCCES;
        });
        builder.addCase(favoriteFetch.rejected, (state) => {
            state.status = Status.ERROR;
        });
    },
});

export default favoriteSlice.reducer
```

Is it worth using a separate file for resampling data, or can it be made easier?
Do Extra reducers need functions for the rest of the queries, or is it enough only for favoriteFetch?
Maybe you should change createAsyncThunk to rtk query?